# Building buy&hold ETF portfolio by writing ETF puts?

Tags: investing, options, etf, market-indexes, options-assignment

Does building a buy and hold index ETF portfolio by writing puts on the desired ETF, and possibily getting assigned, yield a boost over buying the ETF the standard way ? Is it a good idea ?

Comment: @bobbaerker I think the question referencing index ETFs rather than stocks makes it different enough.

Comment: IT makes no difference what the underlying is.  The principal is the same whether it's a stock or an ETF. You sell with the objective of acquiring it at a lower price.  Hopefully the underlying drops and you are assigned, otherwise you just capture a premium.